# How to create a new key in dictionary with value from another key list from a list of dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have this list with 18k dictionary elements (which I'm only showing the part of) in which I need to replace a key and extract an element of the list. For e.g., following is my list of dictionaries.

```
[{'name': 'Achieving_Results_in_a_Challenging_Business_Context_rank = 1.0',
  'column_index': 387,
  'hypergeometric_p_values': [0.04813691453106806, 0.951863085468932],
  'percent_in_group': [0.09896233666410453,
   0.10215470469694621,
   0.11547714514835605]},
 {'name': 'Achieving_Results_in_a_Challenging_Business_Context_rank = 10.0',
  'column_index': 387,
  'hypergeometric_p_values': [0.00014612920992348574, 0.9998538707900765],
  'percent_in_group': [0.08647194465795542,
   0.09316385056580376,
   0.1210906174819567]},
 {'name': 'Achieving_Results_in_a_Challenging_Business_Context_rank = 2.0',
  'column_index': 387,
  'hypergeometric_p_values': [0.044335711647001765, 0.9556642883529982],
  'percent_in_group': [0.09934665641813989,
   0.10261974887614324,
   0.11627906976744186]},
 {'name': 'Achieving_Results_in_a_Challenging_Business_Context_rank = 3.0',
  'column_index': 387,
  'hypergeometric_p_values': [0.000497701807800938, 0.999502298192199],
  'percent_in_group': [0.08724058416602613,
   0.09331886529220276,
   0.11868484362469928]},
 {'name': 'Achieving_Results_in_a_Challenging_Business_Context_rank = 4.0',
  'column_index': 387,
  'hypergeometric_p_values': [0.07220994726016502, 0.927790052739835],
  'percent_in_group': [0.08954650269023828,
   0.0922337622074097,
   0.10344827586206896]}]
```

I need to change `hypergeometric_p_values` to simply `p_values` and only take the first element from the list of the values. Also, I need to create a new key names `percent_missing_group_1` and `percent_missing_group_2` with elements 0 and 1 from the list.

So, the data should be something like this (for a single dictionary):

```
[{'name': 'Achieving_Results_in_a_Challenging_Business_Context_rank = 1.0',
  'column_index': 387,
  'p_values': 0.04813691453106806,
  'percent_missing_in_group_1': 0.09896233666410453,
  'percent_missing_in_group_2': 0.10215470469694621
}]
```

But I've been stuck on this for a while and tried many different ways but all failed. The following one works but it's only for renaming the key

```
data = [{"p_value" if k == 'hypergeometric_p_values' else k:v for k,v in d.items()} for d in data]
```

Also, when I try to do it the following way:

```
for item in cat: 
    for k,v in item.items():
        if k == 'hypergeometric_p_values': 
            item['p_value'] = v[0]
            del item['hypergeometric_p_values']

    print(item)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-397-5298b96a56bc> in <module>
     10 
     11 for item in cat:
---> 12     for k,v in item.items():
     13         if k == 'hypergeometric_p_values':
     14             item['p_value'] = v[0]

RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration
```

Is there any simpler and easier way to do this so that I can rename may keys at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a function to process each elem (or dictionary) in your list and return it. Then, either generate a new list or iterate on your list and edit each element in of list. You must delete the key in the dictionary that you do not need anymore.

```
my_list = [{'name': 'Achieving_Results_in_a_Challenging_Business_Context_rank = 1.0',
  'column_index': 387,
  'hypergeometric_p_values': [0.04813691453106806, 0.951863085468932],
  'percent_in_group': [0.09896233666410453,
   0.10215470469694621,
   0.11547714514835605]},...]

def get_elem(elem):
    elem["p_values"] = elem["hypergeometric_p_values"][0]
    elem["percent_missing_in_group_1"] = elem['percent_in_group'][0]
    elem["percent_missing_in_group_2"] = elem['percent_in_group'][1]
    del elem["hypergeometric_p_values"]
    del elem["percent_in_group"]
    return elem

my_list = [get_elem(x) for x in my_list]
```

or you can iterate on your list if you think it will cause memory error.

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] = get_elem(my_list[i])

>>> my_list[0]
{'name': 'Achieving_Results_in_a_Challenging_Business_Context_rank = 1.0', 'column_index': 387, 'p_values': 0.04813691453106806, 'percent_missing_in_group_1': 0.09896233666410453, 'percent_missing_in_
group_2': 0.10215470469694621}
>>>
```

Not: there may be faster way, but this should work!

Answer (score 0):

I can give you 2 methods to deal with this question:

Method 1: change the keys and values at original data

```
data = [{'name': 'Achieving_Results_in_a_Challenging_Business_Context_rank = 1.0',
  'column_index': 387,
  'hypergeometric_p_values': [0.04813691453106806, 0.951863085468932],
  'percent_in_group': [0.09896233666410453,0.10215470469694621,0.11547714514835605]}]
for e in data:
    p_values = e['hypergeometric_p_values'][0]
    e['p_values'] = e.pop('hypergeometric_p_values')
    e['p_values'] = p_values
    e['percent_missing_in_group_1'] = e['percent_in_group'][0]
    e['percent_missing_in_group_2'] = e['percent_in_group'][1]
    del e['percent_in_group']
print(data)
```

Method 2: build a new data list

```
data = [{'name': 'Achieving_Results_in_a_Challenging_Business_Context_rank = 1.0',
'column_index': 387,
'hypergeometric_p_values': [0.04813691453106806, 0.951863085468932],
'percent_in_group':[0.09896233666410453, 0.10215470469694621,0.11547714514835605]}]

data1 = []
for e in data:
    d = {}
    d['name'] = e['name']
    d['column_index'] = e['column_index']
    d['p_values'] = e['hypergeometric_p_values'][0]
    d['percent_missing_in_group_1'] = e['percent_in_group'][0]
    d['percent_missing_in_group_2'] = e['percent_in_group'][1]
    data1.append(d)
print(data1)
```